# How to get the total number of pages of the existing pdf in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How to get the *total number of pages of the existing pdf* in rails?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use [pdf-reader](https://github.com/yob/pdf-reader) (also available as a ruby gem).
Usage is as simple as

```
reader = PDF::Reader.new("somefile.pdf")
puts reader.page_count
```